# Couchbase lite, Search query taking very long time

Tags: ios, swift, search, couchbase-lite

When I try to search the couchbase documents of size around 10K, the searching is taking very long time. Below are the code snippet. Can anyone optimize it or suggest me any alternative approach. Thank you.

**1) Search function**

```
func search(keyword:String) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
var results:[[String:AnyObject]]=[]
 let searchView = database.viewNamed(AppConstants().SEARCH)

        if searchView.mapBlock == nil {
            startIndexing()
        }

        let query = searchView.createQuery()
        var docIds = Set<String>()

            let result = try query.run()
            while let row = result.nextRow() {
                let key = "\(row.key)"

                let keyArr = keyword.characters.split(" ")
                for (index, element) in keyArr.enumerate() {

                    let keyItem = String(element)

                    if key.lowercaseString.containsString(keyItem.lowercaseString) {
                        let value = row.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                        let id = value["_id"] as? String
                        if id != nil && !docIds.contains(id!) {
                            results.append(value)
                            docIds.insert(id!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**2) Indexing**

```
func startIndexing() {
let searchView = database.viewNamed(AppConstants().SEARCH)
    if searchView.mapBlock == nil {
        searchView.setMapBlock({ (doc, emit) in
            let docType = doc[AppConstants().DOC_TYPE] as! String
            if AppConstants().DOC_TYPE_CONTACT.isEqual(docType) {
                self.parseJsonToKeyValues(doc)

                for value in self.fields.values {
                    emit(value, doc)
                }
                self.fields.removeAll()
            }

            }, version: "1")
    }

}
```

self.parseJsonToKeyValues(doc) will return me the key value store of my documents to index.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're emitting the entire document along with every field for your view.  This could easily cause your queries to be slow.  It also seems unlikely you want to do this, unless you really need to be able to query against every field in your document.
2. It's considered best practice to set your map function right after opening the database.  Waiting until right before you query may or may not slow you down.

See https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html for more, especially the section labeled "Development Considerations".